# Can not run other website in my office

Tags: networking

We can not run any other site on office pc on any pc or laptop connected to my office modem
 why can I only run my company website on office
we tried to change office modem so We can run all sites but my compony website did not open
we tried to connect these two modem together but this did 't work 
The first modem is netgenie on which we can only run company website we do not have login password

The second modem is d-link on which other sites could run but we could not run compant website if we connect through it removing netgenie modem
the ip address for company website is 172.16.10.120 port 8079

Answer (score 0):

Your company website is an intranet site, it does not require general internet access.

Your d-link modem likely has a built-in DHCP server which is turned on by default, and probably provides addresses in the range of 192.168... so your office PC will no longer be on the same subnet as the company website, and therefore cannot access it, although the rest of the internet is available to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir

Comment: But how can we run my company website and other sites together

Comment: Depends on whether or not the modem is your only DHCP server.

If it is, you should configure it to provide addresses in the same range as your netgenie.
If it is not, you should turn off the DHCP server in d-link modem and configure your other DHCP server scope with the router address of the d-link modem.

Comment: netgenie range will probably be something like 172.16.10.1 - 172.16.10.254 on subnet 255.255.255.0
& for the router address: You'll want to restart the d-link modem and look at the DHCP leases in your DHCP server to see what address it has, and then make that the router address in the DHCP scope options.